# SQL datatype with a constraint: each next element is greater/less than the previous one

Tags: sql, sorting, search

Does any of database management systems have a data type (it could be integer or datetime) with a constraint: each next element must be greater/less than the previous one?

Possible use case - storing current timestamp (timestamp should be with fractions of a second to prevent duplicate entries). Such column ends up being presorted and search speed for it is greatly improved without an index.

Comment: Most databases support some method of storing auto incremented ids.  These meet your requirement of uniqueness, even in the case of "simultaneous" transactions, and they are generally increasing based on when the transactions begin.

Comment: Gordon, by integer I meant some user data that might  be growing not linearly. But the main goal is to store timestamps so that the following query is fast: "... where timestamp > time1 and timestamp < time2"

Comment: Then need a column that has a default value of the current date/time.  The user would not set this value, the database would.  Precluding the possibility of resetting the system clock, this should give the behavior you want.  Collisions (same value) would be very, very rare unless you have a very high throughput transaction environment or bulk inserts.

Comment: Gordon, is such case we would not benefit from the fact that the column is presorted. DBMS has to be sure that entries are consecutive and use that advantage.

Comment: What you want occurs with a primary key.  Define an auto incrementing primary key and the database can take advantage of that.  In conjunction with a default `CreatedAt` column, it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Such column ends up being presorted and search speed for it is greatly
>   improved without an index.

SQL database management systems don't support the notion of "presorting" without an index. That index might be explicit or implicit. An explicit index comes about through a CREATE INDEX statement. An implicit index usually comes about through a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint. (The *logical* constraint is usually implemented using a *physical* index.)

There are two issues here: being unique, and being consecutive.

The value of `current_timestamp` isn't guaranteed to be unique, even in serialized transactions. A constraint (like a primary key constraint or a unique constraint) can guarantee that a table *store's* unique timestamps, but it can't guarantee that each transaction will *acquire* a unique timestamp.

Sequential integers--by various names--are guaranteed to be unique and sequential, even in databases with high concurrency. (If you build them that way; you can create a sequence in PostgreSQL that goes backward, for example.) But they're not guaranteed to be consecutive; a rollback will "burn" a number, and the dbms won't try to re-use it.

Finally, the order in which rows are stored doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the order in which they're fetched and presented to the client, even when using an index or a clustered key. The only way to get rows back in a predictable order is to use an ORDER BY clause, which will almost always benefit from an index.

Comment: Mike, it could be user's responsibility to guarantee uniqueness of timestamp, this is not for general usage. On the side of DBMS there could merely be a check that value being inserted is greater than the  last one. And if not, insertion fails.

Comment: *"On the side of DBMS there could merely be a check that value being inserted is greater than the last one."* But you can't do that with declarative code.

Comment: Mike, I understand that. It could be possible if DBMS supported such model.